# App keeps crashing while trying to access image id in seperate activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Whenever I try to set an image in a new activity using its ID my app will crash.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE == 1) {
        ImageView m = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            m.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            p = imageBitmap;
            //REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE++;
        }
    }

    }

    public void saveToList(View w){
        if (REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE == 1) {
            ImageView m = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listA);
            m.setImageBitmap(p);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(GroceryList.this, shopList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

listA is an id in the activity linked to the shopList class.

Is there a way I can set images in an activity outside its linked class?

Comment: check out the stacktrace to learn why it is crashing

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference.

it shows this on the line where I am trying to set the image, but I am not 100% sure what this error means.

Comment: you need to post more code as well as the stack trace. It means that m is null, so findViewById did not find your ImageView in the activity layout.

Comment: I am not really sure why its null.  I am capturing an image and setting m equal to the view for it (which is already made).  It works fine when the view is in the same activity.  If I change 'listA' to 'a' than the program will not crash...

Comment: That `findViewById` is  an activity method that will only find views in the current Activity (specifically in the layout set by the activity's `setContentView` you'll have in `onCreate` ). You cannot access views that belong to other activity. If you need to do that, you'll need to tell the (parent?) activity with a return code and make it change its view.